# Is the cllocationmanager and beacon monitoring kept alive when a new app version is installed?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I have an app that starts a background location manager, that continuously keep track of the users location in the background, and changing the settings of the location manager when beacons are nearby. But I am in doubt of whether or not the location manager will be kept alive in the background if a new version is automatically installed by ios? If not, how should I handle the scenario? I need the location manager to be active across version updates.